# How to perform diallel analysis in R?

Tags: r, experiment-design, genetics

Diallel Analysis using the Griffing and Hayman approach is so common in plant breeding and genetics. I'm wondering if someone can share R worked example on Diallel Analysis. Is there any good referenced book which covered worked examples? Thanks

References:

Griffing B (1956) Concept of general and specific combining ability in relation to diallel crossing systems.  Aust J Biol Sci 9:463-493 [[pdf](http://www.publish.csiro.au/?act=view_file&file_id=BI9560463.pdf)]

Hayman BI (1954) The analysis of variance of diallel tables.  Biometrics 10:235-244 [[JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3001877)]

Hayman BI (1954) The theory and analysis of diallel crosses.  Genetics 39:789-809 [[pdf](http://www.genetics.org/content/39/6/789.full.pdf)]

Comment: a link to a reference paper on "Griffing and Hayman diallel analysis" would be very helpful for non geneticists

Comment: please how can i use SAS for diallel analysis involving three (3) parents.

Comment: Welcome @Musa. this is not an answer to the OP's question. If you have a question yourself, please ask it via the Ask Question button. If you do, please make sure to accurately describe your problem, include a reproducible example or a (toy) data set and perhaps share what you tried so far.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is beta package plantbreeding, which can do diallel analysis.

https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/plantbreeding/

They has a blog:

http://rplantbreeding.blogspot.com/

The following is example from this package:

```
require(plantbreeding)
 data(fulldial) 
 out <-diallele1(dataframe = fulldial, male = "MALE", female = "FEMALE",  
 progeny = "TRT", replication = "REP", yvar = "YIELD" )

print(out) 
out$anvout # analysis of variance 
    out$anova.mod1 # analysis of variance for GCA and SCA effects 
out$components.model1 # model1 GCA, SCA and reciprocal components 
    out$gca.effmat # GCA effects
out$sca.effmat # SCA effect matrix 
    out$reciprocal.effmat # reciprocal effect matrix 

out$varcompare  # SE for comparisions 
    out$anovadf.mod2   # ANOVA for model 2
out$varcomp.model2  # variance components for model 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's unlikely that you'll find worked examples in R for the analysis of diallels.

I did find some references for diallel analysis in SAS (e.g., [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~fisik/SAS_Progeny_Data_Analysis.htm#a3), and there's a chapter on DIALLEL-SAS in the book [Handbook of formulas and software for plant geneticists and breeders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560229497)).

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice worked example in the book [Statistical and Biometrical Techniques in Plant Breeding](http://books.google.com/books?id=9eVQAXTIRwoC&pg=PA184) by Jawahar R. Sharma on about page 184.  Visible in Google books.